# is it possible to setup VPN using external IP(Public) of server through Google Cloud VPN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-vpn

I want to  setup  an IPSec VPN from  a remote ISP Datacenter to  my server located in    Google Cloud through  his external  IP (Not internal  IP of server). 
Is it possible?
All  documentation on Google I found  is about IPSec VPNs with  encryption domain based on  Private IPs (local  & remote ).

Here is what I want to setup:

```
    Remote_Server
     "Public IP"
          |
          |
   "Public_IP_peer"
   [Remote_ISP_Peer]
          |
 (IPSEC_VPN_through_Internet)
          |
  "Public_IP_Google_Cloud_VPN"
    [Google_Cloud_Platform]
          |
          |
  "External_IP_Public"
 Local_Server_in_Google_Cloud
```

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately it's not possible** to use [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview) to connect to *external* IP of your VM instance.

Have a look at the documentation [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview):

> Cloud VPN securely connects your [peer](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/key-terms#peer-definition) network to your [Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs) network through an [IPsec](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) [VPN](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) connection.Traffic traveling between the two networks is encrypted by one VPN gateway, and then decrypted by the other VPN gateway.

and at the section [Specifications](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview#specifications):

> **Cloud VPN only supports site-to-site IPsec VPN connectivity**, subject
> to the requirements listed in this section. It does not support
> client-to-gateway (road warrior) scenarios.

also, at the documentation [Networks and tunnel routing](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/choosing-networks-routing) section [Supported networks](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/choosing-networks-routing#network-types):

> Cloud VPN supports VPC custom networks, auto-mode networks, and legacy
> networks;

In addition, at the documentation [IP Addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses):

> Each VM instance can have one primary internal IP address, one or more
> secondary IP addresses, and one external IP address. To communicate
> between instances on the same Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) network, you
> can use the internal IP address for the instance. To communicate with
> the internet, you must use the instance's external IP address unless
> you have configured a proxy of some kind. Similarly, **you must use
> the instance's external IP address** to connect to instances outside
> of the same VPC network **unless the networks are connected in some
> way, like via [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview)**.

As a result, you'll be able to connect from your on-premises network to *internal* IP of your server only while using [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview).

**As a workaround**, you can [create a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) to allow traffic from remote public IP at [GCP Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) if it's possible in your use case. In some scenarios, you can use [Cloud IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap) for secure access to GCP VM instance via [SSH or RDP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding).

Answer (score 0):

GCP IPsec VPN supports accepting the route with both public IP address range(CIDR block) and private IP address range(CIDR block).  You are free to use both kinds of IP address range(public and private) to point to your on premises networks.
For the detail VPN config please refer to [1](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview)

Comment: How do  i   route traffic coming from  my  premise network through IPSec VPN  to  public IP of my  server inside  GCP ?  How to  send traffic from  server inside GCP using his external IP to  my premise network  ?  because when  i  check  server has only one network  interface configured on  internal IP (private)

Comment: Let  me elaborate more .

Comment: @Zhao let  me elaborate more.                                                                                                         
The objective is  to use a service provided by an ISP in  his DC.For that it recommends following prerequisites:
  have a border equipment supporting IPSec VPN,
  have at least 2 public IPs ,only interco with Public IPs is possible (peer & subnets) to  avoid IP conflict. My  server has 2 IPs (private & public), the Public IP is part of vpn encryption  domainwhich is configured & UP.
But servers aren't reachable from  both side (ISP DC & GCP). any solution?

Answer (score 0):

GCP can accept the route with Public IP address range from Cloud VPN IPSec tunnel. That means in Google Cloud you can access your servers on premises through Public IP addresses via VPN IPsec tunnel. But if you want to access VM instances in Google Cloud through VPN IPsec tunnel, you can only access the VM instances via the private IP addresses. 
Yes, for VM instance, only internal IP address attached to its network interface. The External IP address only using for communication with the Internet. Please refer to [Google public docs for the different IP address range in Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/).

For your case, I can figure all two solutions:
[You can get several public IP addresses from you current ISP, and assign the public IP addresses to the VM instances in Google Cloud and advertise the Public IP addresses back to you ISP environment through the VPN IPSec tunnel](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/custom-public-ip-addresses-on-compute-engine#creating_a_vm_with_a_custom_ip_address)
You just keep using the private IP addresses for your VM instances in Google Cloud, and only advertise the /32 route to your ISP environment, it will have very low risk for getting the IP address conflict.

Comment: @Zhao ,Interesting solution but BGP peering isn't accepted by my ISP  for this service. What  is the second solution  you  figured ?

Comment: @Gabrieldacko the second solution is: You just keep using the private IP addresses for your VM instances in Google Cloud, and only advertise the /32 route to your ISP environment, it will have very low risk for getting the IP address conflict.